# Getting pdf file thumnail when uploading

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I am working on my education website. I use simple php code to upload my pdf files such as books, worksheets... I want the pdf thumnail to display automatically on the links to my read.php page. Can I do that? Please help explain in simple php way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require to use these 2 libraries:

https://www.php.net/imagick

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/

Once you have installed GhostScript:

```
$thumbnails = new imagick('pdf_file.pdf[0]'); // the name of ur pdf file [0] represents page 1

$thumbnails ->setImageFormat('jpg'); // the output format of thumbnails
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

echo $thumbnails; // this will finally output ur thumbanil
```

**Installing GhostScript:** Ref: https://gist.github.com/leomelzer/3949356

1. You have Ghostscript installed, right? Otherwise `sudo apt-get install ghostscript`
2. This is important and installs the headers (iapi.h etc) which are required but don't come with the default Ghostscript package: `sudo apt-get install libgs-dev`
3. I also needed `sudo apt-get install gs-esp`
4. For me the pre compiled version of ImageMagick never accepted Ghostscript, so let's remove it: `sudo apt-get --purge remove imagemagick`
5. Get the source of ImageMagick, untar it, `cd ImageMagick-xx`
6. `./configure --with-gslib=yes` [and what else you need]
7. Confirm in the output near the bottom gslib yes yes and not gslib yes no
8. `make`
9. `make install`
10. Run `convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES => DELEGATES bzlib djvu freetype gs jpeg jng jp2 lcms png tiff x11 xml zlib`
11. See the gs in there? You got it!